# Select query in Symfony error

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine-1.2

I am getting the below error while fetching data from table.

> 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Exception

Couldn't find class tasks_comments

```
$r = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.worked_hours')
     ->from('tasks_comments u')
     ->where('u.tasks_id = ?', $arr_values['tasks_id'])
     ->andwhere('u.id != ?', $arr_values['id']);
$results1 = $r->execute();
```

But, I didn't get any error for another table as the above format. please check and suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
  ->where('u.tasks_id = ?', $arr_values['tasks_id'])
```

to

```
  ->andwhere('u.tasks_id = ?', $arr_values['tasks_id'])
```

Comment: you welcome kishore :) , make sure to accept answer to help others